# Can I use jedi to get the type of an object at a position in a script?

Tags: python

I would like to use static analysis to determine the module path to the type of an object (e.g. a variable name, or instance, etc) at a position in a python script. For example, if somewhere I define:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

and later in the script I use the variable a, and I know the position, I would like to have a function that returns numpy.array,

as another example:

```
from ase import Atoms
a = Atoms([])
```

later, the function would return ase.atoms.Atoms if it was on the a variable. In general it would be the right thing to use as an argument to pydoc would be for the thing at the cursor.

I have looked into jedi but it isn't obvious it can do what I want. Is it possible? Or is there another way to get that information?

Here is an example of what I have figured out so far:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
import jedi

source = '''from ase import Atom, Atoms

a = Atoms([])'''

s = jedi.Script(source, 3)
gd = s.goto_definitions()

print('name: ',gd[0].name)
print('mname: ', gd[0].module_name)
print('mpath: ', gd[0].module_path)
print('line: ', gd[0].line)
print('fname: ', gd[0].full_name)
print('parent: ', gd[0].parent().module_name)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: name:  Atoms
: mname:  atoms
: mpath:  /Users/jkitchin/Dropbox/python/ase/ase/atoms.py
: line:  24
: fname:  atoms.Atoms
: parent:  atoms
```

What I need is "ase.atoms.Atoms". What I want to do with this is be in a Python script in an editor, and run a command that returns the full name of the object at the cursor and then run pydoc on that to see the documentation. The code above is pretty close, but "pydoc atoms.Atoms" is not correct as it is missing the ase at the beginning.

Comment: Are you looking for `type(a).__qualname__`?

Comment: I don't think so. That looks like what you would do in a script, but that isn't what I am trying to do. I don't want to run the script itself, just analyze it.

I edited my question to clarify.